# Thunderbird won't open after a fresh install of 12.04, how to fix?

Tags: thunderbird, email, mail

When I try to open Thunderbird, it opens for 1 second and then force close.

I executed via terminal and I saw this:

`/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined symbol: g_bsearch_array_lookup`

What's happening???

System:
eee Netbook
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 32-Bit OS

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps updating thunderbird to the latest stable version (currently 13) will fix this problem. Open a terminal console and enter:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

After that, your thunderbird should be the latest stable version (and function). I hope this helps.